# Sharing git configuration file across different computers working on the same repository

Tags: git

Me and my colleagues develop software using git for version control. However, it is pretty difficult that we all use the same `--no-ff` policy across different types of merges. We know that this can be configured in `.git/config` for each repo locally or in `~/.gitconfig` for all repositories. And we have seen that this configuration file is very powerful allowing use the [set different default policies for different branches](https://code-maven.com/enforce-fast-forward-as-merge-strategy). However, this file (`.git/config`) is not something that is pushed to the repository. Therefore, we cannot share these defaults across different working computers by just cloning the repository. Is there a way that this config can be automatically set in the repository? We want this configuration file to work similarly to `.gitignore` where everybody working with the repo containing the `.gitignore` has the same ignore policy. I have tested adding a `.gitconfig` with the desired configuration in the root of the git repository (next to `.gitignore`) and it did not work. We also know that we can include a file using `git config --local include.path path-to-file`, but that would require that everybody runs this command after cloning the repository which is not what we want.

Comment: Maybe you could put `config` under the template directory in every machine. The default template path varies on different systems. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory. Unless another template is specified, a newly initialized or cloned repository always has `.git/config` copied from the template.

Comment: Thanks for the template directory tip. It is another approach that we will consider alongside other solutions that we've thought that require more work on the machines than just `git clone ...`.

Answer (score 1):

`git config` has an `include` sections, and also `includeIf` sections ([docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes))

You could choose a convention on where the company's repositories should be cloned (e.g : in a specific `/path/to/company` ? a specific prefix in the projects' names ?), and set an includeIf section once on each workstation in the *global* config.

---

Another way could be to deploy a `git-companyconfig` script on each workstation, so that setting up the config in an existing repo would be a uniform call to `git companyconfig`,
and possibly a `git-companyclone` that would run `git clone xx/project && cd project && git companyconfig`
(obviously, I will let you choose better names for your custom git commands ...)